# inline uppercase chapter title

Tags: titles, chapters, titlesec

Hi I want to put the chapters title in one line and uppercase, I found this code that makes it inline but how ti make it uppercase too

code:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{}
```

Comment: Instead of `{}` try `{\MakeUppercase}`

Comment: thanks this works for the chapter name, I need the chapter number uppercase too

Comment: `\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}`

Comment: didnt work the result of these is "Chapter 1: CHAPTERMarco Teórico" and i want something like "CHAPTER 1: MARCO TERÓICO"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a couple of `\MakeUppercase` instructions:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter:}
  {.5em}
  {\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Marco Teórico}

\end{document}
```

I used `\Large` instead of `\huge` because I got an overfull line with the latter. I also reduced the space between the colon and the title.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}` add to your preamble. It should capitalize the word CHAPTER.