# How to format section headings?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

a question about formatting section titles. In the article class, I want to format my section titles as follows:

- Hide the section number in the title.
- Use upper case.
- Add a dashed title rule below the title (I have custom dashed lines defined elsewhere).

I have tried out a lot with the titlesec package already, but I don't get even near a solution.

```
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\large\titlerule}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
```

This produces a titlerule above my title, but not below. I have tried various places for \titlerule, but I cannot find the correct one^^. Also, \MakeUppercase does not work on the titlename. The section numbers are visible. Can anyone help?

Best,
a

Comment: hello, could you give us a MWE ?

Answer (score 16):

Like so?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\large}{}{0em}{\MakeUppercase}[\titlerule]
\begin{document}
\section{This}
\end{document}
```

(Some hints were found in [inline uppercase chapter title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253533/inline-uppercase-chapter-title))

---

The general syntax of `\titleformat` is

```
\titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]
```

- `<command>` is the sectioning command you want to modify, here `\section`.
- `<shape>` determines the general placement of the heading, see page 3 in the manual for a list of options. This is an optional argument.
- `<format>` holds general format switches for the text of the heading, here `\centering\large`.
- `<label>`: This is where you place code that prints the number of the section (`\thesection`), and other related  things, e.g. the word *Chapter* for chapters.
- `<sep>` is the distance from the number to the title (I just changed this to 0em)
- `<before-code>` is just that, code placed before the text of the title. `\MakeUppercase` takes an argument (i.e. `\MakeUppercase{text}`), but as I understand it `titlesec` is constructed so that the last macro used in `<before-code>` can take an argument, and you can use it as I have.
- `<after-code>` as expected is placed after the title text. You wanted the rule after, so I added it here. This is also an optional argument, brackets (`[]`) typically denote optional arguments in LaTeX, while braces (`{}`) denote mandatory arguments. For that reason you cannot leave out the empty pair of braces.

Comment: Thank you, that worked so far, but could you help me a little further by explaining the logic behind placing those {} [], some of which are empty? I did read the titlesec documentation, but, well, I don't understand. Cheers, a

Comment: @anne I'll try adding some, though I'm hardly an expert on `titlesec`. Will update in a few minutes.

Comment: @anne You know that there is a manual to the package, right? The syntax of the command is described in detail in the manual.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you very much, very useful, I just needed a little more explanation than the manual offered. Got it!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. Just to sum up the lesson learned, I want to add an example of how I formatted the subsection headings with lines etc. The code is:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\large}{}{0em}{\MakeUppercase}[\titlerule]
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\upperdots\\\large}{\thesubsection}{1.5em}{\MakeUppercase}[\basedots]
```

Note that (upper|base)dots are custom lines defined using the dashrule package. The result may not be perfect, but it looks ok for now: [image: 1]

Comment: Where is that `\upperdots` command comes from?