# How can I use expl3 text_uppercase for hyperref bookmarks with German umlauts?

Tags: formatting, hyperref, expl3, bookmarks, german

When I use `text_uppercase` with German umlauts and hyperref option "unicode=true", the umlauts get replaced by 'A's with a tilde in the bookmarks. I set the option "unicode=true" due to the fact that I have to use greek letters for the numbering of one of the section levels. For that I use 'textgreek'-letters, which only work in the bookmarks with the hyperref unicode option... Is there any solution to that problem?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    unicode=true,
    bookmarksnumbered=true
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN\textupper\text_uppercase:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\textupper{Über die Einöde}}% umlauts get replaced in bookmarks
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems to work but I didn't check many cases.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    unicode=true,
    bookmarksnumbered=true
}

%\usepackage{bookmark}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\textupper{}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands
  {
    \cs_set:Npn\textupper #1{ \use:e {\text_uppercase:n {#1}} }
  }

% if also in the headings 
%\cs_set_eq:NN\textupper\text_uppercase:n
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\textupper{Über die Einöde}}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: A real pro.... - Thank you so much!! (It seems to work perfectly..)