# Case change of UTF-8 characters breaks them in PDF metadata

Tags: unicode, expansion, characters, cases, metadata

I was using an expandable macro to change case of a text stored in another macro. The result was used in several parts of the document and in the PDF metadata. Here I encountered an interesting problem – in the document body both the original and changed characters (including UTF-8) are rendered correctly, whereas in PDF metadata only non-UTF-8 processed characters are rendered as expected (while unprocessed UTF-8 characters are displayed properly).

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \MakeExpandableLowercase \text_lowercase:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={AbcÆæ}, % Works.
    pdfauthor={\MakeExpandableLowercase{AbcÆæ}}, % Does not work!
}

\begin{document}

\noindent AbcÆæ.\\ % Works.
\MakeExpandableLowercase{AbcÆæ}. % Also works.

\end{document}
```

The result is as follows (using Adobe Reader DC to view the PDF metadata):

- `AbcÆæ` in document text is rendered as ‘AbcÆæ’,
- `AbcÆæ` in PDF metadata is rendered as ‘AbcÆæ’,
- `\MakeExpandableLowercase{AbcÆæ}` in document text is rendered as ‘abcææ’,
- `\MakeExpandableLowercase{AbcÆæ}` in PDF metadata is rendered as ‘abcÃ¦Ã¦’ (should be ‘abcææ’).

Is it possible to fix the last point, i.e., to be able to change case of a UTF-8 text in an expandable manner and use the result in PDF metadata?

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be expandable?  Maybe your MWE gives a simple case, but the actual use will require expandability?  Maybe you are just curious about the behavior itself...

Comment: `\MakeLowercase` does not go well with metadata (as well as `\lowercase` which also fails for UTF-8) or sectioning (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/548401, http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-casechange). I noticed this particular problem when replacing some recurring words in text (that also occur in lowercase as PDF keywords) with macros to facilitate future changes. I can overcome this by retyping keywords by hand, but this is just a workaround and there is probably a more TeX-relevant way to automate this. Also, I am indeed curious about the solution, as all my own attempts have failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that while `\text_lower:n` is expandable, it returns its result wrapped in a `\unexpanded`. This means that the `æ` is not expanded to the LICR-command but stays as `æ` in the text. One needs a second `edef` step. You can see this by doing two `\edef` manually and then view the result:

```
% first edef:
\edef\testI   {\MakeExpandableLowercase{AbcÆæ}}
\show\testI   % gives abcææ.
% second edef:
\edef\testII  {\testI}
\show\testII  % gives abc\OT1\ae \OT1\ae
% for comparision:
\edef\testIII {AbcÆæ}
\show\testIII % abc\OT1\ae \OT1\ae
```

hyperref is handles only content that is expanded in one step. You would get a similar output with

```
     pdfauthor={\unexpanded{æ}}
```

One way to get around it, would be two expand twice, e.g. with `\expanded`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \MakeExpandableLowercase \text_lowercase:n
\cs_new:Npn \MakeTwiceExpandableLowercase #1 { \expanded {\text_lowercase:n {#1}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={AbcÆæ}, % Works.
    pdfauthor={\MakeTwiceExpandableLowercase{AbcÆæ}}, %
}

\begin{document}

\noindent AbcÆæ.\\ % Works.
\MakeExpandableLowercase{AbcÆæ}. % Also works.

\end{document}
```